# Is term "metric" for evaluating machine learning model misnomer?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, definition

Term "metric" is used in many popular machine learning articles [[1](https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-to-evaluate-your-machine-learning-algorithm-f10ba6e38234), [2](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/11-important-model-evaluation-error-metrics/))] for describing an evaluation criterium of the performance of a model. Although, mathematically is the term defined as:

> In mathematics, a metric or distance function is a function that defines a distance between each pair of elements of a set. [[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))]

Should we use the term or use more general term "measure"?

Comment: Think about how the math nerds use "normal".

Comment: Unfortunately the word "measure" also has a formal definition in [mathematics (i.e. measure theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)).